How to declare a friend function for a template class?
As the title says, I'm not sure what is the correct syntax for declaring a friend function for a template class. I have tried the following, but none of them compiles: (with g++: g++ -std=c++14 -g test.cpp -o debug.exe -Wall)
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Test{
    private: T x;

    public: Test(const int &x): x(x) {}

    public: friend void test(const Test<T> &obj);
    //warning: friend declaration ‘void test(const Test<T>&)’ declares a non-template function
};

template <typename T>
void test(const Test<T> &obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
    //error: ‘int Test<int>::x’ is private within this context
}

int main() {
    Test<int> obj(15);
    test<int>(obj);
}

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Test{
    private: T x;

    public: Test(const int &x): x(x) {}

    public: template <typename T> friend void test(const Test<T> &obj);
    //error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter
};

template <typename T>
void test(const Test<T> &obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Test<int> obj(15);
    test<int>(obj);
}

For now the only working code I know is: (from declare template friend function of template class)
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Test;
template <typename T> void test(const Test<T> &obj);
//Why do I need these forward declaration?
//If I remove them, I get these errors:
/*
test.cpp:9:25: error: variable or field ‘test’ declared void
    9 |     public: friend void test<T>(const Test &);
      |                         ^~~~
test.cpp:9:25: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
    9 |     public: friend void test<T>(const Test &);
      |                         ^~~~
      |                             ;
test.cpp:9:29: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
    9 |     public: friend void test<T>(const Test &);
      |                             ^
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void test(const Test<T>&) [with T = int]’:
test.cpp:19:14:   required from here
test.cpp:14:22: error: ‘int Test<int>::x’ is private within this context
   14 |     std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
      |                  ~~~~^
test.cpp:5:16: note: declared private here
    5 |     private: T x;
      |                ^
*/

template <typename T>
class Test{
    private: T x;

    public: Test(const int &x): x(x) {}

    public: friend void test<T>(const Test &);
};

template <typename T>
void test(const Test<T> &obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Test<int> obj(15);
    test<int>(obj);
}

How can I do this correctly?
Also, my actual purpose for asking this question is to achieve non member function operator overloading with a template class (so that operator should be able to access private member of the class, if the class itself does not have any public method to access the private data). This should be possible right?

How you do it correctly depends on what you are trying to achieve, and your code samples (collectively) are trying to do multiple things.   What is test() and what do you want it to be a friend of?    You see, test() may be a single function or it may be a (templated) set of functions.  And, whatever it is, it might be a friend of all specialisations of Test<T> or it might be a friend of Test<X> but not a friend of any Test<Y> where X and Y are distinct types.  For each possibility, the approach is different.

Simpler in that case is to put definition inside the class directly.

@Peter test() is just a test function which I want it to be a friend of class Test so that it can access 'private: T x;'. And for what I really intended to do, please read the last sentence of the question.

@Jarod42 Please read the last sentence of the question.

I mean something like that.

Once fixed the shadowing, your first code also works Demo. but is not equivalent to mine: your have template function test (where test<Y> can access private part of Test<X>).

And with your second code, test is still template, but test<Y> can only access private part of Test<Y>, not from Test<X> (but test<X> can).

@Alison - You're missing my point.   There is no class Test in your code, since it is a template that forms the basis for a family of classes (if X and Y are distinct types, Test<X> is a distinct class from Test<Y>).  Similarly, a templated function specifies a family of functions.    And my question amounts to "for each class Test<T> in that family of classes,  which functions test<X>() in that family of functions will be its friends?".  The fact you don't see a distinction is probably central to difficulty you are experiencing.

@Peter The one with the same type. That is, test<X>() will be a friend of class Test<X>, and is able to access its private members, but not class Test<Y>.

Modify your first example as follows  (1)   Add two declarations before defining the template Test as follows:  template<typename T> class Test; and template<typename T> void test(const Test<T> &);.    (2)  Modify the friend declaration to friend void test<T>(const Test<T> & obj)  (note the <T> after the name test and before the opening ().   Roughly speaking, your problem is due to needing to declare test() before Test<T> can declare it as a friend, and needing to declare Test<T> before declaring a function test() that accepts a Test<T> & argument.

Aside:  having a constructor argument named x and a member named x will also often trigger compiler warnings (although valid C++, the meaning of Test(const int &x) : x(x) {} often differs from what mere mortals expect it to be, so compilers often warn about it).   To address that (and reduce muttering from people - including possibly yourself - who have to maintain your code in future) the member and the function argument need to have different names.
